# Auto-updating Mulitple dropdown vlues in jquery with hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, dropdown, show-hide

I am having three drop-downs, But only one drop-down will be visible initially.
While selecting a value in the first drop-down then the second drop-down will be visible. the same way if we select a value for second drop-down then the third drop-down will be visible

Whenever i reset the value for the previous drop-down i want the next drop-down to be reset to **-- please select --** (which is not currently happening)

**For example (I need this output)** :

```
drop-down 1 
    -- please select --
    option 1.1
    option 1.2
drop-down 2
    -- please select --
    option 2.1 (1.1)
    option 2.2 (1.1)
    option 2.3 (1.1)

    option 2.4 (1.2)
    option 2.5 (1.2)
    option 2.6 (1.2)
    option 2.7 (1.2)

drop-down 3
    -- please select --
    option 3.1 (2.1)
    option 3.2 (2.1)
    option 3.3 (2.1)

    option 3.4 (2.2)
    option 3.5 (2.2)

    option 3.6 (2.3)
    option 3.7 (2.3)

    option 3.8 (2.4)

    option 3.9 (2.5)

    option 3.10 (2.7)
    option 3.11 (2.7)
    option 3.12 (2.7)
    option 3.13 (2.7)
    option 3.14 (2.7)
```

Here is the html, its slightly different

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Dropdown 1</label>
<select name="select1" id="fe296151">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
  <option id="main1" value="aaaa-1">aaaa-1</option>
  <option id="main2" value="bbbb-1">bbbb-1</option>
  <option id="" value="cccc-1">cccc-1</option>
</select>
<div id="divselect2">
  <label>Dropdown 2</label>
  <select name="select2" id="fe296152">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
    <option id="sub1" class="main1" value="aaaa-1-2.a">aaaa-1-2.a</option>
    <option id="sub1" class="main1" value="aaaa-1-2.b">aaaa-1-2.b</option>
    <option id="sub2" class="main2" value="bbbb-2.a">bbbb-2.a</option>
    <option id="sub2" class="main2" value="bbbb-2.b">bbbb-2.b</option>
    <option id="sub2" class="main2" value="bbbb-2.c">bbbb-2.c</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="divselect3">
  <label>Dropdown 3</label>
  <select name="select3" id="fe296154">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
    <option id="red1" class="sub2" value="aaaa-3.a">aaaa-3.a</option>
    <option id="" class="sub2" value="aaaa-3.b">aaaa-3.b</option>
    <option id="" class="sub2" value="bbbb-3.c">bbbb-3.c</option>
    <option id="" class="sub2" value="bbbb-3.d">bbbb-3.d</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="divselect3a">
  <label>input box</label>
  <input type="text" class="red1" value="" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divselect2").hide(); 
  $("#divselect3").hide();
  $("#divselect3a").hide();  
 });
$("#fe296151").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#fe296152 option').clone());
  }
   var fe296151 = $("#fe296151").find(':selected').attr('id');
  if(fe296151) {
    $('#divselect2').show();  
  }
  else {
    $('#divselect2, #divselect3, #divselect3a, #divselect4').hide();  
    }
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('.'+fe296151);
  $('#fe296152').html(options);   
});
$("#fe296152").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#fe296154 option').clone());
  }
  var select2 = $("#fe296152").find(':selected').attr('id');
  if(select2) {
    $('#divselect3').show();  
  }
  else {
    $('#divselect3, #divselect3a, #divselect4').hide();  
    }
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('.'+fe296152);
  $('#fe296154').html(options);
});
$("#fe296154").change(function() {
 
  var select3 = $("#fe296154").find(':selected').attr('id');
  if(select3) {
    $('#divselect3a').show();  
  }
  else {
    $('#divselect3a').hide();  
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Html Code added

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all unnecessary parts for your question. In your logic you were checking if the selected option was without the "ID" attribute, but the "select" options are disabled and you cannot select these values. In my version I show and reset all input elements after the modified one.

I hope this was the result you were looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#divselect2").hide();
  $("#divselect3").hide();
  $("#divselect3a").hide();

  $("#fe296151").change(function() {
  /*
    if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#fe296152 option').clone());
    }
    */
    
    $('#divselect2').show();
    $('#divselect2 select, #divselect3 select, #divselect3a input[type="text"]').val("");
    $('#divselect3, #divselect3a').hide();
    
    
    //var options = $(this).data('options').filter('.' + fe296151);
    //$('#fe296152').html(options);
  });
  
  
  $("#fe296152").change(function() {
    /*
    if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
      $(this).data('options', $('#fe296154 option').clone());
    }
    */
    
    $('#divselect3').show();
    $('#divselect3 select, #divselect3a input[type="text"]').val("");
    $('#divselect3a').hide();
    
    
    /*
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('.' + fe296152);
    $('#fe296154').html(options);
    */
  });
  
  
  $("#fe296154").change(function() {

    $('#divselect3a').show();
    $('#divselect3a input[type="text"]').val("");
    
  });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Dropdown 1</label>
<select name="select1" id="fe296151">
  <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
  <option id="main1" value="aaaa-1">aaaa-1</option>
  <option id="main2" value="bbbb-1">bbbb-1</option>
  <option id="" value="cccc-1">cccc-1</option>
</select>
<div id="divselect2">
  <label>Dropdown 2</label>
  <select name="select2" id="fe296152">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
    <option id="sub1" class="main1" value="aaaa-1-2.a">aaaa-1-2.a</option>
    <option id="sub1" class="main1" value="aaaa-1-2.b">aaaa-1-2.b</option>
    <option id="sub2" class="main2" value="bbbb-2.a">bbbb-2.a</option>
    <option id="sub2" class="main2" value="bbbb-2.b">bbbb-2.b</option>
    <option id="sub2" class="main2" value="bbbb-2.c">bbbb-2.c</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="divselect3">
  <label>Dropdown 3</label>
  <select name="select3" id="fe296154">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please select</option>
    <option id="red1" class="sub2" value="aaaa-3.a">aaaa-3.a</option>
    <option id="" class="sub2" value="aaaa-3.b">aaaa-3.b</option>
    <option id="" class="sub2" value="bbbb-3.c">bbbb-3.c</option>
    <option id="" class="sub2" value="bbbb-3.d">bbbb-3.d</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="divselect3a">
  <label>input box</label>
  <input type="text" class="red1" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for the Help! Here i want like this optput with hide/show dropdown one by one**

```
drop-down 1 
    -- please select --
    option 1.1
    option 1.2
drop-down 2
    -- please select --
    option 2.1 (if i choose option 1.1, i want to show this option)
    option 2.2 (if i choose option 1.1, i want to show this option)
    option 2.3 (if i choose option 1.1, i want to show this option)

    option 2.4 (if i choose option 1.2, i want to show this option)
    option 2.5 (if i choose option 1.2, i want to show this option)
    option 2.6 (if i choose option 1.2, i want to show this option)
    option 2.7 (if i choose option 1.2, i want to show this option)

drop-down 3
    -- please select --
    option 3.1 (if i choose option 2.1, i want to show this option)
    option 3.2 (if i choose option 2.1, i want to show this option)
    option 3.3 (if i choose option 2.1, i want to show this option)

    option 3.4 (if i choose option 2.2, i want to show this option)
    option 3.5 (if i choose option 2.2, i want to show this option)

    option 3.6 (if i choose option 2.3, i want to show this option)
    option 3.7 (if i choose option 2.3, i want to show this option)

    option 3.8 (if i choose option 2.4, i want to show this option)

    option 3.9 (if i choose option 2.5, i want to show this option)

    option 3.10 (if i choose option 2.7, i want to show this option)
    option 3.11 (if i choose option 2.7, i want to show this option)
    option 3.12 (if i choose option 2.7, i want to show this option)
    option 3.13 (if i choose option 2.7, i want to show this option)
    option 3.14 (if i choose option 2.7, i want to show this option)
```

**Note : We don't have the (2.6) sub option for drop-down 3**